# JavaFX TableView update cell, does not update the object value

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

After making a column editable as a textfield, and being able to edit and update the value shown inside the cell, I noticed that whenever i tried to extract the updated value from the tableview, only the old original unedited value was returned to me - It seems like the value represented inside the cell does not equal to the one returned from the underlying model object.

To make my colum editable i use the following code:

```
ObservableList<TableColumn> colums = search.getColumns();

colums.get(1).setEditable(true);
colums.get(1).setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataPoint>forTableColumn());
colums.get(1).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataPoint, String>("No"));
```

A short snippet of the DataPoint object is as shown below

```
public class DataPoint {
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    /* Constructor not shown in example */

    // Get Number
    public String getNo() {
        return this.data.get(1);
    }

    public void setNo(String No) {
        this.data.set(1, No);
    }
}
```

To extract the value of the cell, the following code is used:

```
DataPoint selectedData = (DataPoint) TableView_Search.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

System.out.println(selectedData.getNo());
```

So how would I save this updated value inside the model object / how could i extract the **shown** value inside the cell?

(My GUI is a FXML document made with the Scene Builder program from Gluon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the `cellValueFactory` returns a property that also allows you to write to the item, you need to use the `onEditCommit` event to store the value in the item. `PropertyValueFactory` returns a property that does not write to the item, if just the getter and setter but no property getter exists in the item class.

```
((TableColumn<DataPoint, String>) colums.get(1)).setOnEditCommit(evt -> evt.getRowValue().setNo(evt.getNewValue()));
```

---

Alternatively you could use a `JavaBeanStringProperty` returned from the `cellValueFactory` to achieve this effect:

```
JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder builder = JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().beanClass(DataPoint.class).name("no");
colums.get(1).setCellValueFactory(cd -> builder.bean(cd.getValue()).build());
```

Comment: I tried to add the first line of code you gave me, but my IDE tells me it cant resolve the method: "Cannot resolve method 'getRowValue()'" same goes for "getNewValue" - Do you know what the problem might be ?

Comment: Probably the fact that you're using the raw type. Should be fixed, if you add the appropriate cast. (See edit).

Comment: Thanks, that most definitely seems to fix my problem !